# Elixir, num = [9], num gets assigned to '\t'

Tags: elixir

```
iex> num = [9]
'\t'
```

Assigning a single list of [9] returns '\t'. What would be the reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [i helper in IEx](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#i/1) for more information on data types:

```
iex> i [9]  
Term
  '\t'
Data type
  List
Description
  This is a list of integers that is printed as a sequence of characters
  delimited by single quotes because all the integers in it represent valid
  ASCII characters. Conventionally, such lists of integers are referred to as
  "char lists" (more precisely, a char list is a list of Unicode codepoints,
  and ASCII is a subset of Unicode).
Raw representation
  [9]
Reference modules
  List
```

If you want to inspect the raw representation you can pass `char_lists: false` to `inspect`:

```
IO.inspect('abc', char_lists: false)
[97, 98, 99]
```

Comment: how would I get the original value 9 into num out of it?

Comment: The value is `[9]`, IEx just represents it as a list of ASCII characters. See my edits.

Comment: Sorry maybe I am not explaining correctly. I need pull 9 out of the list as 9 and bound to a variable. But in a comprehension, 9 comes out as '\t'

Comment: `[num | _tail] = [9]`

Comment: Ok. I was being misled by the shell. When you run that expression it prints '\t' to the shell but n is bound to 9. Thank you Gazler!

Comment: `hd [9]` will also display 9.